# how to find switch statement from an ast generated from pycparser?

Tags: python, c, regex, abstract-syntax-tree, pycparser

I am trying to parse c files using pycparser and find the switch statement
I have generated the ast using https://github.com/eliben/pycparser/blob/master/examples/explore_ast.py this link.
then using n = len(ast.ext) i have found the length of the exts generated from the ast.
Now i have to find the  switch statement from the ast
i tried doing
if re.findall(r'(switch(\s*'),ast.ext)
and match regex to find switch case but it isnt happening.
How to proceed with this as i am entirely new to pycparser and have no idea about it

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, please include your code (as a minimal reproducible example) in your question, rather than linking other sources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't run regexp matching on pycparser ASTs!

There are multiple examples in the pycparser repository that should help you: `explore_ast.py`, which you've already seen lets you play with the AST and explore its nodes.

`dump_ast.py` shows how to dump the whole AST and see what nodes your code has.

Finally, `func_calls.py` demonstrates how to walk the AST looking for specific kinds of nodes:

```
class FuncCallVisitor(c_ast.NodeVisitor):
    def __init__(self, funcname):
        self.funcname = funcname

    def visit_FuncCall(self, node):
        if node.name.name == self.funcname:
            print('%s called at %s' % (self.funcname, node.name.coord))
        # Visit args in case they contain more func calls.
        if node.args:
            self.visit(node.args)
```

In this case `FuncCall` nodes, but you need switch nodes, so you'll create a method named `visit_Switch`, and the visitor will find all `Switch` nodes.

Comment: class SwitchNodeVisitor(c_ast.Switch,switch_node):
    def _init_(self,switch_node):
     self.switch_node = switch_node
     def visit_SwitchNode(self , node):
          if node.name.name == self.switch_node:
              print('%s called at %s' %(self.switch_node , node.name.coord))
          if node.args:
              self.visit(node.args)

Comment: i am trying it like that but it isnt happening i am not understanding how to do

Comment: @BHASWATISENGUPTA: could you update your question with a properly formatted code snippet that gives you trouble, as well as a clear explanation of what the issue is - what you're seeing vs. what you expect?

Comment: my question is : i need to find switch statement in any c code which will be parsed.so by seeing the git repo pycparser i generated the ast from explore ast.now the problem is i have to find the switch node and print it from the ast..but i am unable to do that .Last time you told me to use the example of function call.py from examples directory but i am not able to do it..i tried finding switch by directly printing the switch_node from ast_transforms.py but it didnt generate any result.

Comment: I even imported fix_switch_cases from ast_transforms.py in explore_ast and then called the function **fix_switch_cases(switch_nodes)** but the output is showing "switch_node not defined"..so how will i do that that i am not getting

Comment: @BHASWATISENGUPTA: for more help, either edit your question or open a new issue for pycparser. You **HAVE TO PROVIDE**: a minimal code sample (C file with some code and the switches you want to find) demonstrating your issue, and a minimal Python sample that uses pycparser to find switches, demonstrating what's not working